# Bokeh Figure looks strange when using float instead of integer in ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, csv, types, bokeh

I have a problem creating a simple figure in Bokeh using ColumnDataSources- The results look different for using data in integer or float. The figure looks very strange when using float64 but it looks the way it should look when using integer64.

I am working with Bokeh since last summer (switched to 0.12.4. this week, Python 2.7.13) and I was able to solve my problems by the help of google - till now.

**So thats my Problem:**
I want to plot a timeseries of data (float) which is saved as csv-file (named 'test.csv') and read into a dataframe. The csv-file looks like this

```
i;T
0;1.02
1;2.02
2;3.02
3;4.02
4;3.04
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure


df=pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=' *; *', engine='python')
source_01 = ColumnDataSource(
            data=dict(
            x=df['i'], 
            y=df['T']))

p01 = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=600)
p01.circle('x', 'y', source=source_01)

l1 = layout([ 
  [p01] 
])

curdoc().add_root(l1)
```

When plotting a simple figure based on this data it looks like this [Figure (with float64)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spMXQ.png) and I am getting the information "ColumnDataSource's columns must be the same length". But for my understanding the columns are the same length.

Using a csv-file with int64

```
i;T
0;1
1;2
2;3
3;4
4;3
```

it looks like the following [Figure (with int64)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnv3Z.png) and I dont get any warnings according length of columns.

I have no idea whats happening in the first figure - hope someone can help me and show me where I am making a mistake - thanks.

Comment: I'm also using bokeh version 0.12.4 and I've tested your code and I don't see that problem. Pandas problem? I'm using pandas version 0.19.2

Comment: I also can't reproduce. What is your operating system?

Comment: Thanks for your answers - I am using Pandas 0.19.2 to.

Comment: Operation System - Windows 7

Comment: if it matters - Windows 7 - 32bit

Comment: possibly https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7384